# Highest and lowest value of nested lists using recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

I want to take in a list with nested lists. Then print the highest value of index 0 or 2 in the list and the lowest value of index 0 or 2, through using recursion.

This is what I got so far:

```
lst = [1, 5, [7, 10, []]]

def high_low(my_list):
    new_lst = []
    if not my_list:
        print max(new_lst)
        print min(new_lst)
    elif isinstance(my_list[0], int):
        return new_lst.append(my_list[0]) + high_low(my_list[2:])
    elif isinstance(my_list[0], list):
        return new_lst.append(max(my_list[0])) + high_low(my_list[2:])
```

This is where I get stuck, as I don't know how to get the highest and lowest value from a nested list and then append it to the new empty list. For example this is what I want the output to look like:

```
>>> print_tree(lst)
10 
1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be achieved using a similar & classic problem solving ([Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)), no need to reinvent the wheel, just use some working method & post-process:

Flatten the list of lists, then take min & max of it.

```
import collections

def flatten(l):   # function copied from the link above
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, (str, bytes)):
            yield from flatten(el)
        else:
            yield el

lst = [1, 5, [7, 10, []]]

new_list = list(flatten(lst))  # create a list cos we'll be iterating twice on it
print(max(new_list))
print(min(new_list))
```

result

```
10
1
```

with one iteration with a manual loop:

```
min_value = None
max_value = None
for v in flatten(lst):
    if min_value is None or v < min_value:
        min_value = v
    if max_value is None or v > max_value:
        max_value = v

print(min_value)
print(max_value)
```

the `flatten` method is nice because it doesn't create temporary `list` elements so no unneccesary memory allocations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility to write the code with only one pass, no need for external library or python's `min/max`:

```
def high_low(list_or_number):
    if isinstance(list_or_number, list):
        current_min = float('inf')
        current_max = float('-inf')
        for x in list_or_number:
            x_max, x_min = high_low(x)
            if x_max > current_max:
                current_max = x_max
            if x_min < current_min:
                current_min = x_min
        return (current_max, current_min)
    else:
        return (list_or_number, list_or_number)
```

As an example:

```
>>> high_low([1, 5, [7, 10, [[12, 16], -10]]])
(16, -10)
>>> high_low(3)
(3, 3)
>>> high_low([3,4,5])
(5, 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following recursive function that returns the maximum and minimum among the items in the current list and the maximum and minimum of the sublists:

```
def high_low(l):
    try:
        l.extend(high_low(l.pop()))
    except AttributeError:
        return [l]
    except IndexError:
        return []
    return max(l), min(l)
```

so that:

```
lst = [1, 5, [7, 10, []]]
print(high_low(lst))
```

outputs:

```
(10, 1)
```

Comment: Looks nice. However I want it to work for different cases and not just one.

Comment: Okay, I had trouble understanding how it works. The thing is, it doesn't.

Comment: @Blueshirt In which cases does it not work? Can you update your question with such cases?

Comment: `print(high_low([3,5]))` or `print(high_low([3,[5, 7]]))` for example.

Comment: @EricDuminil I see. I've fixed it for those cases then.

Comment: @Blueshirt Does my updated answer for EricDuminil fix your different cases as well?

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work : `high_low([[3,5],7])` returns `([3, 5], 7)`

Comment: @EricDuminil I'm fairly sure that all of the OP's input lists are only nested at the last index of a parent list, as evident by his sample input as well as his attempt to perform recursion on a slice of index 2 to the end of a list in his code.

Comment: It could be. But that would make for a suprising/buggy method. It's not so hard to write a method which works for any nested list.

Comment: @EricDuminil If that's the data model the OP is deciding on using, then there's nothing wrong to implement methods around that exact data model. But then again, I can hardly imagine a case where the OP's data model can be meaningfully useful.