# Finding the lowest value in a list of lists recursively

Tags: python, list, loops, recursion

I'm making a function where I have to find a the lowest value in a list of lists recursively. For example, a list containing [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]] would return 1.

I have some code written already. However, I don't know how to iterate through a list and compare the lowest number to a list.

I have included a comment where my function gets an error in my code below:
def recMin(nestedLis):

```
lowest = 1000000

if len(nestedLis) < 2:
    return nestedLis
else:
    # This function works until it hits a list in a list (ex. [1, 2])
    # because it cannot compare a list to an int. I don't know how to fix this
    if nestedLis[0] < lowest:
        lowest = nestedLis[0]
        print(lowest)
    return lowest + recMin(nestedLis[1:])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want.

```py
import collections

def flatten(l):   # function copied from the link above
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, (str, bytes)):
            yield from flatten(el)
        else:
            yield el

new_list = list(flatten(lst))
print(max(new_list))
```

This was from this post: [Highest and lowest value of nested lists using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52576825/highest-and-lowest-value-of-nested-lists-using-recursion)

Comment: You should vote to close this as a duplicate, not repost from another answer

Comment: oh im not completely familiar with stackoverflow, but ill do that then